# redirection based on domain name instead of file name

Tags: web-server, mac-osx, .htaccess, redirect, filemaker

I have 10.8 Server with Filemaker Server 12 running two pages in Instant Web Publishing.

The pages are accessible locally:

```
http://192.168.168.42/fmi/iwp/cgi?-db=exampleONE&-loadframes
http://192.168.168.42/fmi/iwp/cgi?-db=exampleTWO&-loadframes
```

If I access the server at exampleONE.mydomain.com I can have the Web Services redirect index.html to http://exampleONE.mydomain.com/fmi/iwp/cgi?-db=exampleONE&-loadframes

If i access exampleTWO.mydomain.com it of course loads the same index.html file and redirects to the exampleONE page. I would like to have the server differentiate between exampleONE.mydomain.com/index.html and exampleTWO.mydomain.com/index.html

I am using the Redirects feature built into OS X Server GUI app. Is this possible in that, or with .htaccess?

My DNS provider does not allow redirects, but I can set A records and CNAMES.

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite, you could fashion a rewrite rule either in your httpd.conf file, or by using the .htaccess.

For example

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)example(ONE|TWO)(.*)$ http://example$2.mydomain.com$1example$2$3 [P,L]
```